# How to display data without using JOIN and Counting Number of employees?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am having trouble with this question I can't seem to get the count correct 
on each department and only select the highest one as well as excluding 
"DALLAS"

THIS IS THE QUESTION

"Write a SQL statement to display the name and location of all departments 
(except the departments located in Dallas) with the highest number of 
employees.

You cannot use join operations in your SQL statement (e.g., … FROM department, 
employee WHERE …,  department INNER JOIN employee ON …)."

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME      LOCATION           
------------- -------------------- --------------------
           10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK             
           20 RESEARCH             DALLAS               
           30 SALES                CHICAGO              
           40 IT                   DALLAS               
           50 EXECUTIVE            NEW YORK             
           60 MARKETING            CHICAGO              

 6 rows selected

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME        JOB_TITLE                                          SUPERVISOR_ID HIRE_DATE     SALARY COMMISSION DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------- --------- ---------- ---------- -------------
       7839 KING                 PRESIDENT                                                        20-NOV-01       5000                       50 
       7596 JOST                 VICE PRESIDENT                                              7839 04-MAY-01       4500                       50 
       7603 CLARK                VICE PRESIDENT                                              7839 12-JUN-01       4000                       50 
       7566 JONES                CHIEF ACCOUNTANT                                            7596 05-APR-01       3000                       10 
       7886 STEEL                PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT                                           7566 08-MAR-03       2500                       10 
       7610 WILSON               BUSINESS ANALYST                                            7596 03-DEC-01       3000                       20 
       7999 WOLFE                TEST ANALYST                                                7610 15-FEB-02       2500                       20 
       7944 LEE                  REPORTING ANALYST                                           7610 04-SEP-06       2400                       20 
       7900 FISHER               SALES EXECUTIVE                                             7603 06-DEC-01       3000        500            30 
       7921 JACKSON              SALES REPRESENTATIVE                                        7900 25-FEB-05       2500        400            30 
       7952 LANCASTER            SALES CONSULTANT                                            7900 06-DEC-06       2000        150            30 
       7910 SMITH                DATABASE ADMINISTRATOR                                      7596 20-DEC-01       2900                       40 
       7788 SCOTT                PROGRAMMER                                                  7910 15-JAN-03       2500                       40 
       7876 ADAMS                PROGRAMMER                                                  7910 15-JAN-03       2000                       40 
       7934 MILLER               PROGRAMMER                                                  7876 25-JAN-02       1000                       40 
       8000 BREWSTER             TBA                                                              22-AUG-13       2500                          
       8100 PHILLIPS             TBA                                                         7839 21-AUG-13       2800                          
       7400 SMITH                VICE PRESIDENT                                              7839 16-FEB-01       4300                       50 
       7700 ANDRUS               PUBLIC ACCOUNTANT                                           7566 18-FEB-02       2500                       10 
       7601 SAMPSON              PROGRAMMER                                                  7910 09-JAN-01       2500                       40 
       7588 DODSON               TEST ANALYST                                                7610 02-AUG-08       2500                       20 
       7888 SANDY                SALES CONSULTANT                                            7900 05-AUG-04       2500                       30 

 22 rows selected





SELECT  DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
            location, 
            count(*)

    FROM    DEPARTMENT
    WHERE   department_id IN (  SELECT      department_id
                                FROM        department
                                WHERE       UPPER(location) <> 'DALLAS' 
                              ) 

    group by department_NAME, location
    ORDER BY    location;



DEPARTMENT_NAME      LOCATION               COUNT(*)
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
MARKETING            CHICAGO                       1 
SALES                CHICAGO                       1 
ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK                      1 
EXECUTIVE            NEW YORK                      1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using sub-queries if you are limited in not using joins

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT d.department_name,
               d.location,
               (SELECT COUNT(employee_id)
                  FROM employee e
                 WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id) no_employees
          FROM department d
         WHERE d.location <> 'DALLAS'        
       ) t
WHERE no_employees = (SELECT COUNT(employee_id)
                        FROM employee
                       WHERE department_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT department_id
                                                 FROM department
                                                WHERE location <> 'DALLAS')
                       GROUP BY department_id
                       ORDER BY 1 DESC
                       LIMIT 1)
```

Result

```
department_name location    no_employees
SALES           CHICAGO     4
EXECUTIVE       NEW YORK    4
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, it says Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis". I tried adding one and it still didn't work. I tried ending it with a semi colon. Still getting the error.

Comment: are you using oracle?

Comment: I was using sql developer

Comment: I was asking for the rdbms you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to the find the department with maximum count and then retrieve the corresponding name and location without using joins

```
SELECT  (SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME, location 
           FROM DEPARTMENT
          WHERE department_id = q.department_id) , 
            q.ct countofdept
    FROM 
             (SELECT count(*) ct, department_id
               FROM EMPLOYEE
            WHERE department_id in (  SELECT      department_id
                                            FROM        department
                                           WHERE       UPPER(location) <> 'DALLAS' 
                                         ) 
           GROUP BY department_id
           ORDER BY ct desc
           LIMIT 1) q
```